# How do I get a helper method in a utility class to use its callers logger in log4net?

Tags: logging, log4net

I have an executable that depending on the command line switch supplied looks something like:

**Program.cs -**

```
namespace DiskSpaceReporting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if(args.Length == 1)
            {
                switch(args[0])
                {
                    case "-summarytotals":
                        SummaryDiskSpaceReporter.Run();
                        break;

                    case "-detailed":
                        DetailedDiskSpaceReporter.Run();
                        break;
                    //...other reporting types
                }



            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SummaryDiskSpaceReporter.cs**

```
namespace DiskSpaceReporting
{
    public class SummaryDiskSpaceReporter
    {
        private static IEventIDLog log = EventIDLogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public static void Run()
        {
            log.Info(1234, "Starting");
            //...do work
            string message = Helpers.CreateMessage(messageID);
            //...do work
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailedDiskSpaceReporter.cs**

```
namespace DiskSpaceReporting
{
    public class DetailedDiskSpaceReporter
    {
        private static IEventIDLog log = EventIDLogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public static void Run()
        {
            log.Info(1234, "Starting");
            //...do work
            string message = Helpers.CreateMessage(messageID);
            //...do work
        }
    }
}
```

**Helpers.cs**

```
namespace DiskSpaceReporting
{
    public class Helpers
    {
        private static IEventIDLog log = ???            
        public static string CreateMessage(Guid messageID)
        {
            log.Info(9876, "Starting");
            //...do work
        }
    }
}
```

In my log4net config I have two separate loggers, one for each of the SummaryDiskSpaceReporter and DetailedDiskSpaceReporter because their logging requirements are different:

```
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleLogAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
</root>

<logger name="DiskSpaceReporting.SummaryDiskSpaceReporter">
    <appender-ref ref="SummaryDiskSpaceReporterRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="DiskSpaceReporting.DetailedDiskSpaceReporter">
    <appender-ref ref="DetailedDiskSpaceReporterRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Both SummaryDiskSpaceReporter and DetailedDiskSpaceReporter call a helper method in a class called Helpers. I want to put some logging into the helper class methods.

So...the question is, how do I get the Helpers.CreateMessage() method to use the same logger as its caller?

i.e.

> SummaryDiskSpaceReporter.Run() -> use
>   DiskSpaceReporting.SummaryDiskSpaceReporter
>   logger DetailedDiskSpaceReporter.Run()
>   -> use DiskSpaceReporting.DetailedDiskSpaceReporter
>   logger.

Cheers
Kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been playing with this question for quite some time and unfortunately have to give up for a while and return to doing "real" work. For the moment what I have come up with is as follows:

**Options 1:** Pass the logger in

This is not a great option, but should work fine if you do not mind coupling your helper to a logger. Simply allow your CreateMessage method to take a IEventIDLog. You can then use this to log to the correct passed in logger.

```
public static string CreateMessage(Guid messageID, IEventIDLog log)
{
    log.Info(9876, "Starting");
    //...do work
}
```

Not exactly shiny, but it should work!

**Options 2:** Use the call stack

Make use of the call stack to find the calling code and from this find the type and get the logger you want from that type

```
public static string CreateMessage(Guid messageID)
{
    StackFrame frame = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1);
    IEventIDLog log = EventIDLogManager.GetLogger(frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType);
    log.Info(9876, "Starting");
    //...do work
}
```

Still not shiny since we need to touch the call stack and what happens if the calling code does not have a logger.

**Option 3:** use log4net

This is the option we want to use, hell it is what the question wants as its answer, *but I have not yet worked it out **yet***. :) Looking through log4net we find cool things like the Hierarchy class that allows us to get the root logger.

```
Logger logger1 = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy) log4net.LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
```

So I am sure there is a way to get the logger one level up from CreateMessage method, now just to find it. :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response....I thought about options 1 & 2, but there must be a way to get log4net to do this for free as it were.